# How to save activity data?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was searching for the proper answer, but I could not find it. All of them did not work for me. Basically I have an activity with five EditText fields(input type is number). What I want to do is that when that activity is closed and re-opened that it does not lose those numbers that were inputted. I believe that there is an easy solution, any kind of help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: use [haredPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Agreed with Prag's, use SharedPreferences

Comment: SharedPreferences mypreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypreferences.edit();
editor.putString("stringName", "stringValue"); editor.commit();    i found that but it is for strings

Comment: How to use it, can you explain a bit? please

Comment: You can use the putLong/getLong instead. Read up on SP a bit more maybe.

Comment: So, I need to use that SharePreferences in onDestroy method or?

Comment: Use it in onStop or onPause

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To do what you want you can use Shared Preferences:

To obtain shared preferences, use this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To read preferences:

```
String dateTimeKey = "com.example.app.datetime";
// use a default value using new Date()
long l = prefs.getLong(dateTimeKey, new Date().getTime());
```

To edit and save preferences

```
Date dt = getSomeDate();
prefs.edit().putLong(dateTimeKey, dt.getTime()).apply();
```

Comment: method getActivity() and getSomeDate() are undefined?

Comment: if you are inside Activity class use "this". use getActivity() if you are in a fragment class

Comment: is an example function to generate a Date. For your case, to save Strings you use putString instead of putLong and you dont need to generate dates